# How I can optionally set visible property of GtkCellRenderer?

Tags: c, gtk

I have already GtkTreeView. And I want hide some cells.

There is method

```
gtk_cell_renderer_set_visible  (GtkCellRenderer *cell, gboolean visible);
```

But How I can apply this method for some cells? Use iterator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is to 'mask' your model using a [`GtkTreeModelFilter`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTreeModelFilter.html). With this, you can supply an extra 'visible' column that tells whether the row should be visible or not; or you can use a function to decide which rows should be visible.